# Equality of array to a dIfferent type of variable

Tags: c, arrays, recursion

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int reverse(char v[],int i,int j){
   char temp;//what happens if a define temp as an integer 
   if(j==1)
       return 1;
   temp=v[i];//computations
   v[i]=v[j];//computations
   v[j]=temp;//computations

   reverse(v,++i,--j);
 }


int main(void){
    char test[]="jimmakos";
    reverse(test,0,strlen(test)-1);
    printf("%s",test);
    return 0;
 }
```

This is a program to reverse a string. I don't understand why the program still works if I define `temp` as an `int` instead of `char` in function `reverse()`.  Since the elements of the array `v[]` are `char` type how do the computations work?

Comment: `char` **is** an integer.

Answer (score 1):

An `int` can store all possible values that a `char` can store, plus more.

So assigning a `char` value to an `int` preserves that value, and assigning back to a `char` also preserves the value since the value came from a `char`.

Answer (score 1):

You're fine in this instance, since any `char` instance is *guaranteed* to fit into an `int`.

(Note that a *literal* like `'j'` in C is an `int` type with a guarantee that it can fit into a `char`).

Answer (score 0):

There will be truncation, and you will get warnings from the compiler.

Since characters are small integers too, assigning to/from integers of a different size is conceptually not so complicated, but in practice of course you can drop bits due to the differences in precision.

There's of course no *point* in having `temp` be an integer, and I'd instead go for a `const char`.